# What is the tk/tkinter event type "Property" and how does one use it?

Tags: python, events, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I have a canvas and I want to run a function whenever the *scrollregion* of the canvas has changed.

Looking over the documentation for binding events, it listed **Property** as an event type and defined it as follows:

> [**Property**](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/bind.htm#M19)
>
> > A Property event is sent to a window whenever an X property belonging to that window is changed or deleted. Property events are not normally delivered to Tk applications as they are handled by the Tk core.

Sounded like exactly what I wanted, but that is most I could find on the subject anywhere...

What is this thing and how do you use it?

---

Experimenting on my own:

- `canvas.bind("<Property-scrollregion>", lambda e: print("Scrollregion has changed! ", e))`

  Throws an error saying *scrollregion* is not a property.
- `canvas.bind("<Property>", lambda e: print("Something changed. ", e))`

  Doesn't react to anything I've tried so far.

Note: Whether a **Property** event is what I can or should actually use for the mentioned task is a moot point, I mainly want to fill this hole in the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used tk and tkinter for close to 20 years and I've never had a need for that event. It is a left-over from when tk only worked on X-windows (aka X11) based systems, and isn't very relevant today.

Notice how the definition says specifically "X property'. The "X" here refers to the X windowing system, and an [X property](http://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/window-information/properties-and-atoms.html) is a very specific thing, such as a window colormap. While it is true that a tiny number of X property names map to widget attribute names (for example, FONT), they are not the same thing as the widget attributes.

The bottom line is that it does not do what you think it does. It cannot be used to notify you when an attribute of a widget has changed.

Comment: Alright, thanks.
I kinda could tell it wasn't right, but I disliked not knowing what it is.